# Adding `@SpringBootTest` annotation triggers IntelliJ false positives

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

So If you have a test class

```
class FooControllerIT{
    @Autowired FooController controller;
}
```

and you add an `@SpringBootTest` annotation to the class, IntelliJ claims that

> Could not autowire. No beans of 'FooController' type found.

Which is a lie because the tests run and pass just fine.

If I replace the `@SpringBootTest` annotation with, say, an `@Component` annotation, the "error" disappears (and re-appears when I substitute the `@SpringBootTest` annotation back in again).

What causes this behaviour?

(I'm on ultimate 2019.1, using Spring Boot 2.1.8-RELEASE)

Comment: Please add test class code. What exactly you test?

Comment: @ValeriyK. It doesn't matter. Anything, really, that uses the controller.

Comment: Does it work with Spring Boot lower version, for example, 2.0.3? Did you add @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) at the top of the test class? Do you use testng or junit?

Comment: @ValeriyK. We're using `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` (for Junit), but yes, I did add it.

Answer (score 0):

The possible way that your Controller cannot be found is that it is not in the same (or higher) package as your main application class annotated `@SpringBootApplication`. If you don't want to move the Controller, you can create a new configuration class that will be annotated as `@ComponentScan`

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.your.controller.package")
public class FooConfig {
}
```

Even that you can add this config manually to your test spring context: `@SpringBootTest(classes = FooConfig.class)`